# Out-of-sync Replication in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

Okay, a little complex:

1. One local DB table is being replicated to another local DB with same table. Worked for years. User account on replication job is gone, so job was failing. I updated it to a different account, and every 10 minutes, it had no errors then. However, it didn't replicate a new row.
2. I manually created the new record in the subscriber DB table.
3. Restarting the server ended up working, but now the replication fails because it has the queue of new records it's trying to add and the identity column value already exists in the destination table.

Options: Should I...

1. Delete the records I added so that the replication can copy down the new records?

   - Problem: Not sure if the used IDs will be able to be used with the new records coming over in the replication (because of the auto-numbering identity column), and we need those IDs to remain matched.
2. Somehow clean out the queue so that those records aren't attempted any more (since I already created them) -- not sure how to do this.

Yes, I searched a lot on this stuff, but I haven't seen this problem described in the same way.

Thanks for any help or answer!

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to drop the subscription.

You're getting primary key violations as the replication agent is trying to insert duplicates.

> 1. Delete the records I added so that the replication can copy down the new records?

Yes, you will need to manually remove the records in order to alleviate the primary key violations.

Comment: Just to drive this home, don't ever make manual DML changes at the subscriber.  The whole topology makes assumptions based on it being the only thing changing data there.  Change those assumptions and the whole thing falls apart.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to re-create your publication
2. Drop the subscription
3. Sync data from old subscriber database to the publisher - use something like Redgates Data Compare, it will generate the change scripts for you - OR write you own sync script
4. re-create the subscription

Comment: Okay, I know they're in sync, so I'll just drop it and recreate it.  Thanks!

Comment: That's not the correct solution to the problem! While it will work well in the end, it's like getting an axe at a barber shop :-). There are solutions to replication synchronization issues. Please see [my question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/how-to-fix-discrepancies-between-publisher-and-subscription-data) and the details in it (plus the answer and the comment).